# Convert number in scientific notation to string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to convert a scientific number to a string in Matlab but using a rather specific format. I started with the following:

```
>> num2str(1E4, '%e')

ans =

    '1.000000e+04'
```

Then played around with the formatstring to get rid of the digits after the decimal point in the first part

```
>> num2str(1E4, '%.0e')

ans =

    '1e+04'
```

The thing is I want it exactly how I am expressing it in numbers, namely I want a string like this `'1E4'`. I could use `strrep` to get rid of that plus sign but I refuse to use it to get rid of the leading 0 on the `+04` part since I have other instances of the variable which have things like `+10`. It it feasible to reproduce the number as a string without resorting to some big complicated algorithm? Preferably using the formatstring?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

According to [num2str](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) documentation, you need to use a format parameter of and precision parameter as follows:

```
num2str(1E4,'%.E')
```

**Result**

```
ans = 1E+04
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about *sprintf* .  LEt *A* be your number, to achieve what you want, you can use:

```
sprintf('%1.0e',A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to convert integers to scientific notation:

```
function out= scientific(num)
    E = 0;
    if mod(num,10) == 0
        [f n]=factor(num);
        E=min(n(ismember(f,[2 5])));
    end
    out = sprintf('%dE%d',num/10^E,E);
end

>> scientific(134)
ans = 134E0
>> scientific(134000)
ans = 134E3
```

Another solution that accepts input as vector:

```
function out= scientific2(num)
    E = sum(cumsum(num2str(num(:))-48,2,'reverse')==0,2);
    out = num2str([num(:)./10.^E,E],'%dE%d\n');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html).

```
my_format = @(x)regexprep(sprintf('%.E',x),'E\+0*','E');
```

Examples:

```
>> my_format(1E4)

ans =

1E4

>> my_format(2E12)

ans =

2E12
```

This is not ideal for all cases:

```
>> my_format(5) % Expect 5E0

ans =

5E

>> my_format(1E-4) % Expect 1E-4

ans =

1E-04
```

We can fix the first case with a [token](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html#btrgp70-2):

```
f2 = @(x)regexprep(sprintf('%.E',x),'E\+0*(\d)','E$1');

>> {f2(1E4), f2(1E20), f2(5)}

ans = 

    '1E4'    '1E20'    '5E0'
```

And we can fix the second case with tokens and a [`?` quantifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_d0e853509):

```
>> f3 = @(x)regexprep(sprintf('%.E',x),'E\+?(-?)0*(\d)','E$1$2');
>> {f3(1E4), f3(1E20), f3(5),f3(1E-1),f3(2E-12)}

ans = 

    '1E4'    '1E20'    '5E0'    '1E-1'    '2E-12'
```

To explain, `sprintf('%.E',x)` formats `x` in scientific notation with `E`, e.g. `1E+04`, then it finds

```
'E\+?(-?)0*(\d)'

 E                 The literal E
  \+?(-?)          Either a + or a -; if - then save to group $1
         0*        As many 0s as it can match, subject to...
           (\d)    At least one digit, saves digit to group $2
```

Finally, the matched text is replaced with `E$1$2`, that is the literal `E`, then group `$1` (a minus sign if found `E-`, nothing if found `E+`) and the group `$2` (a single digit).